# What does it mean when a PostgreSQL process is "idle in transaction"?

Tags: postgresql

What does it mean when a [PostgreSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) process is "idle in transaction"?

On a server that I'm looking at, the output of "ps ax | grep postgres" I see 9 PostgreSQL processes that look like the following:

```
postgres: user db 127.0.0.1(55658) idle in transaction
```

Does this mean that some of the processes are hung, waiting for a transaction to be committed?  Any pointers to relevant documentation are appreciated.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/monitoring-ps.html) indicates that this means the transaction is open (inside BEGIN) and idle.  It's most likely a user connected using the monitor who is thinking or typing.  I have plenty of those on my system, too.

If you're using Slony for replication, however, the [Slony-I FAQ](http://slony1.projects.postgresql.org/slony1-1.2.6/doc/adminguide/faq.html) suggests `idle in transaction` may mean that the network connection was terminated abruptly.  Check out the discussion in that FAQ for more details.

Comment: What does only 'idle' mean?? Are the transactions in 'idle' state also open?

Comment: What does *monitor* mean?

Comment: @Abdull The psql client. "Monitor" is an (apparently) archaic term for the software used to control a database.

Comment: @YousufSultan See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/202028/26781

Answer (score 25):

As mentioned here: [Re: BUG #4243: Idle in transaction](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-bugs/2008-06/msg00102.php) it is probably best to check your pg_locks table to see what is being locked and that might give you a better clue where the problem lies.