# Getting "idle in transaction" for postgresql with django

Tags: django, postgresql

We are using Django 1.3.1 and Postgres 9.1

I have a view which just fires multiple selects to get data from the database.

In Django documents it is mentioned, that when a request is completed then ROLLBACK is issued if only select statements were fired during a call to a view. But, I am seeing lot of "idle in transaction" in the log, especially when I have more than 200 requests. I don't see any commit or rollback statements in the postgres log.

What could be the problem? How should I handle this issue?

Answer (score 5):

First, I would check out the related post [What does it mean when a PostgreSQL process is “idle in transaction”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019/what-does-it-mean-when-a-postgresql-process-is-idle-in-transaction) which covers some related ground.

One cause of "Idle in transaction" can be developers or sysadmins who
have entered "BEGIN;" in psql and forgot to "commit" or "rollback".
I've been there. :)

However, you mentioned your problem is related to have a lot of
concurrent connections. It sounds like investigating the "locks" tip
from the post above may be helpful to you.

A couple more suggestions: this problem may be secondary. The primary
problem might be that 200 connections is more than your hardware and
tuning can comfortably handle, so everything gets slow, and when things
get slow, more things are waiting for other things to finish.

If you don't have a reverse proxy like Nginx in front of your web app,
considering adding one. It can run on the same host without additional
hardware.  The reverse proxy will serve to regulate the number of
connections to the backend Django web server, and thus the number of
database connections-- I've been here before with having too many
database connections and this is how I solved it!

With Apache's prefork model, there is 1=1 correspondence between the
number of Apache workers and the number of database connections,
assuming something like Apache::DBI is in use. Imagine someone connects
to the web server over a slow connection. The web and database server
take care of the request relatively quickly, but then the request is
held open on the web server unnecessarily long as the content is
dribbled back to the client. Meanwhile, the database connection slot is
tied up.

By adding a reverse proxy, the backend server can quickly delivery a
repliy back to the reverse proxy and then free the backend worker and
database slot.. The reverse proxy is then responsible for getting the
content back to the client, possibly holding open it's own connection
for longer. You may have 200 connections to the reverse proxy up front,
but you'll need far fewer workers and db slots on the backend.

If you graph the db slots with MRTG or similar, you'll see how many
slots you are actually using, and can tune down max_connections in
PostgreSQL, freeing those resources for other things.

You might also look at [pg_top](http://ptop.projects.postgresql.org/) to
help monitor what your database is up to.

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is an older question, but this article may describe the [problem of idle transactions in django](http://thebuild.com/blog/2010/10/25/django-and-postgresql-idle-in-transaction-connections/).

Essentially, Django's TransactionMiddleware will not explicitly COMMIT a transaction if it is not marked dirty (usually triggered by writing data). Yet, it still BEGINs a transaction for all queries even if they're read only. So, pg is left waiting to see if any more commands are coming and you get idle transactions.

The linked article shows a small modification to the transaction middleware to always commit (basically remove the condition that checks if the transaction is_dirty). I'll be trying this fix in a production environment shortly.

Comment: As of django 1.3, [database reads mark the transaction as dirty](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9964#comment:51). Thus a COMMIT is executed even if no writes are issued. The article linked to on thebuild.com, while a good analysis, is out of date.